# Recover corrupted password protected Zip

Tags: encryption, file-encryption, data-recovery, zip, recovery

Good evening.
I have a password protected `zip` archive (Zip 2.0 CryptoZip) with a `.txt` file with sensitive info inside. The problem is that I can't extract it.

- 7Zip:`"Data error : Wrong password?"`
- WinRar:`"CRC failed in the encrypted file. Corrupt file or wrong password"`

I'm pretty sure I enter the right password, because when I try any different passwords it just ends up with `"wrong password"`.

I reproduced the same error by the following steps:

- Created a password protected `zip` with a single txt file inside
- Edited some of the bytes using `Hex` editor
- Tried to extract the `zip` using my password and got the same error.

My question is simple: is there any way now to extract the txt file from this corrupted password protected zip?

I tried to "repair" the zip using WinRAR, Object Fix Zip, DiskInternals Zip Repair, Recovery Zip Toolbox, Zip2Fix. None of them could help me, the "repaired" `zip` is still broken and I get the same error.

Thank you.

Comment: I believe (but not with enough authority to create an answer) that your reason for believing you're using the right password is false. While there may be situations where an extraction program could _provably_ determine between a wrong password and a corrupt file, I suspect that in many cases it cannot be certain which is which.

Comment: Now I actually think so too, because I can't extract even a single byte of the file..

Answer (score 1):

If the ZIP file only holds that one TXT file, then I'm afraid chances of recovery are low.

Try visually inspecting the file's hex dump. A "true", undamaged ZIP file should contain high-entropy, random values (all the more so if it's encrypted too). If there are large swaths of repeated filler characters (0x00, 0xC0, 0xA9, 0xFF...), then that section of file is almost certainly corrupt.

On some systems (e.g. Linux console with no buffering) you can try and extract the file with `unzip -c`. This will result in the file beginning decryption and output, and failing as soon as it hits the corrupted block. The data up to that point will be extracted normally.

## Special cases

- A whole block of size 512, 1024, 2048 or 4096 bytes in the ZIP is empty (filled with zeroes, FFs, or the like). This is almost certainly due to the hardware support the ZIP file was on, going corrupt. The sector has been replaced by nulls. If you still have the original support you may try recovering that. If it was a hard disk, it was a bad hard remap of a damaged sector, and the data is lost (unless you can interface at a **very** low level with the disk itself, which is brand- and disk- dependent). Chances of recovery are essentially nil.
- The ZIP file appears intact. No obvious blanks inside. There is a possibility: the file was transferred with CRLF conversion, and **ALL** its LF's have become CRLF's pairs. This happens once every 256 bytes on average and you can verify it by counting how many naked CR's, how many naked LF's, and how many CRLF pairs are in the file. If this is the case, you will have to locate all those pairs and remove the extra CR, and each time verify whether the decoding progresses or not. Usually, by re-zipping the partially recovered file (after truncating any ending garbage) with the same algorithm, you can come up with an intact ZIP file that you can compare with the damaged one to determine the position, in the ZIP stream, of the error (i.e.: if the zipped fragment is 7291 bytes long, then in the damaged zip file, at around offset 7291 relative, there is an error). I had this happen to me once, and was able to recover the file; I remember it took a whole night, though.

Comment: Thank you for you reply!
I just tried 'unzip -c', didn't work for me, I got 'invalid compressed data to inflate' error. That makes me think maybe the encryption header is corrupted. Btw, is there a chance that I'm just trying the wrong password? I mentioned above that I'm not completely sure about it's correctness. However, trying other passwords gives me just 'password incorrect--reenter'.
I'll check the special cases, thanks!